# Set Session With Post Data

Tags: php, mysql, session

So I'm trying to use laravel-based login table, which is the hash that I can't even compare it with basic php hash login. No, you can't make hash exactly look like laravel. But I use the `remember_token` that is come from `users` table.

Here is the code on my laravel view:

```
<form action="http://localhost/log/index.php" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" value="{{ Auth::user()->remember_token }}" name="wex">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Check</button>
</form>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to POST `remember_token` value, that will received on my `http://localhost/log/index.php` as variable.

Index.php (Keep in mind, this is not using laravel):

```
<?php
    include "koneksi.php";

    if (isset($_POST['wex'])) {
        $token = $_POST['wex'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE remember_token = '". $token ."'" ;
        $result = mysqli_query($db_link,$query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 1) {
            header("Location: http://localhost/laralearn/public/login");
        }

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['user'] = "member";
    }
    else{

        if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
            header("Location: http://localhost/laralearn/public/login");
        }
    }


?>
```

The variable and page redirect if the `remember_token` isn't valid (working), but I can't set the session. When I tried to open the index.php on new tab, it's redirecting which is meaning the session isn't settled.

Can you tell me where am I doing something wrong? It would be nice if you explain it and tell me what the code should look like.

Thank you.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: I'll check it out! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `session_start();` right under the PHP tag. It must be called before there is any output and just to be on the safe side, include it before there is anything else called either.

Comment: `<?php include "koneksi.php";` right after this line sir?

Comment: Do this..

<?php
session_start();
include "koneski.php";