# Session Can't Be Set and return Null

Tags: php, function, session

So here is the code for eppkm.php (the page that I need to be protected)
The session is settled simply by submit a form that have token value.

```
<?php session_start();
include_once"pengaturan/crud.php";

if (isset($_POST['token'])) 
{
        $token = $_POST['token'];
        $_SESSION['user'] = true;
        $konek->login($token);
}
else
{
        $_SESSION['user'] = true;
        $konek->login($token);
}

?>
```

And here is the pengaturan/crud.php file, login function:

```
public function login($token)
    {

      if (isset($token)) 
      {  
        $query = "SELECT * FROM master_users WHERE remember_token = '". $token ."'" ;
        $hasil = pg_query(Parent::get_dbcon(),$query);

        if (pg_num_rows($hasil) != 1)
        {
          echo "nothing";
          //header("Location: http://192.168.0.190/eppkm_ex/public/master/login");       
        }

      }

      else{
        if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
        session_destroy();
        header("Location: http://192.168.0.190/eppkm_ex/public/master/login");
          }
      }

    }
```

When I tried to echo the session, it says `Undefined index: user` and also tried var_dump the session, the result comes to null which mean the session isn't settled.

Can you help me fix the session? And point me where am I doing wrong :(

Comment: I ever have same problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44938763/set-session-with-post-data

Answer (score 0):

I've encounter similar issue in the past *7-8 years ago*  from what I remember the issue is not related to $_SESSION but the value Boolean

I would suggest converting em to string/integer or alternatively per explanation below

here's explaination:

> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is
> converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and
> forth between boolean and string values.

[Reference here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting)

Comment: Yes, i change `$_SESSION['user'] = $token`, but nothing happened. The problem is same, session not settled.

Comment: are you trying to redirect page after setting session?  if Yes can you try adding session_write_close(); above redirect code like example:

session_write_close();
header("Location: /yourpage.php");

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine !

[Check](https://3v4l.org/hIQAP)

Please set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at top of the file or [CHeck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438060/showing-all-errors-and-warnings).